# Как разместить Floating action button поверх map fragment

Tags: android, xml, виджет

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом я бы мог поместить fab поверх map fragment. Скорее всего я просто чего то не понимаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SMarker"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="AddMA"
            android:text="Set Marker" />

    </LinearLayout>
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="464dp"
        tools:context="com.example.karas.mapv2.MapsActivity" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: так как вы используете linearlayout у вас элементы могут быть только друг за другом. используйте relativelayout как корневой, тогда
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" и android:layout_alignParentRight="true" должны заработать

Comment: @YungBlade Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SMarker"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="AddMA"
    android:text="Set Marker" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="464dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
```

Comment: Не проще `FrameLayout`?

Comment: Можно и его, Coordinator по моему наследник Frame.

Comment: Так и есть, но координатор имеет свои фичи, которые необязательны в этом случае. Зачем делать лишнее?  Вы же не идете покупать машину если сдулось колесо?

Comment: Да, согласен!  Исправил ответ.